# Use data from input controller in other, output controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use data from one controller in another one. Which is the best way to achieve this?

I have input and output controllers and their views:

Input controller:

```
AppControllers.controller('DateCtrl', [
  '$scope','$http',
  function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/dates').then(function(response){
      $scope.years = response.data.years
      $scope.months = []
      for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        $scope.months.push(response.data.months[i])
      }
    })
  }
]);
```

Input view:

```
  <div class="input-dual" ng-controller="DateCtrl">
    <div class="input-dual-inner">
      <span>Datum polaska:</span>
      <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="year as year for year in years">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Output controller:

```
AppControllers.controller('DataOutput', [
  '$scope','$http',
   function($scope, $http){

   }
]);
```

Output view:

```
  <div ng-controller="DataOutput">
    {{ selectedYear }}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way it will be to get your http method to service and use this service in every controller where you need it :) 
https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services